# optimizing row number query

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am using sql server 2008 r2 and had below query

```
select * from
(        
    select d.ID as ID,
           ....
           ....        
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (
                ORDER BY #some field                           
           ) AS RowNum
    from
    /*some table*/
    LEFT join 
    (select Device_ID,          
            Level,          
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Device_ID order by id desc) as rn
     from #sometable as de WITH (NOLOCK)
     where #some condition
     ) t
     where t.rn = 1)tmp on ID=tmp.Device_ID **/* sort operation 1*/**
     /*some more joins */
     WHERE /*some condition*/
) as DbD
where RowNum BETWEEN @SkipRowsLocal and (@SkipRowsLocal + @TakeRowsLocal - 1)
order by RowNum
```

I am trying to implement pagination kind of query from sample 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/14/sql-server-tricks-for-row-offset-and-paging-in-various-versions-of-sql-server/

but looks like it's executing very slow, when I looked into query plan sort operation is consuming almost 50% of query time and i guess its the 1st sort operation which I marked as 1, basically in temp table t I want to retrieve latest value and in outer row number I wanted to fetch say only 40 records.

It's basically like sorting 10K rows and then taking 40 out of it, is there is any way we can improve this query?

Comment: Execution plan and table definition, please

Comment: have you got an index DeviceId, id?  Also an index over 'ORDER BY #some field'  - whatever the #some field is?

Comment: Try to turn `where t.rn = 1` into `outer apply (select top 1` without row_number (the second one).

Answer (score 0):

instead of a left join, try an OUTER APPLY, to get the TOP 1 of the device you are interested in - think of it as 'I get a record from the first table, then for that record, I go and get the TOP 1 for that device ID in the other table, but remembering that in the second table, you need to search by the data from the first table, rather than a join

```
    select * from
        (        
         select    d.ID as ID,
                   ....
                   ....        
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                   (
                        ORDER BY #some field                           
                    ) AS RowNum
            from
            /*some table*/
            OUTER APPLY
            (select TOP 1 Device_ID,          
                    Level          

                        from #sometable as de WITH (NOLOCK)
                        where #some condition and Device_ID = [/*some table*/].id ORDER BY id DESC
            ) t
            )tmp 
            /*some more joins */
            WHERE /*some condition*/
       ) as DbD
       where RowNum BETWEEN @SkipRowsLocal and (@SkipRowsLocal + @TakeRowsLocal - 1)
       order by RowNum
```

something on those lines, you might want to build just the relevant parts of the query and compare them, it would seem to avoid sorting and with an index might well be quick